# Is is possible to sniff POLL / NULL packets for bluetooth protocol with tcpdump?

Tags: bluetooth, tcpdump

I'm trying sniffing **POLL/NULL** packets from bluetooth (BT) protocol using tcpdump. 
As far as I understand POLL / NULL packets are packets (ACL?) sent between a master and a slave BT devices to keep track of connection syncronization info (clock drift, jitter, delta etc) If I create an l2cap connection between two devices and I do not send any data packet on it, I would expect to see those packets anyway. (is this correct?)
I'm sniffing the BT traffic with tcpdump but I cannot see any packet captured, but the data packet send over the l2cap layer. 
Are those packets generated at the "wire" level by the BT radio chip, so tcpdump cannot capture them?

Many thanks 
Sergio

P.S. here's the tcpdump command I'm using: 
**`sudo ./tcpdump -n -s0 -tt -vv -i bluetooth0 -w bt_tcpdump.pcap`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POLL/NULL packets are exchanged at a very low level in the link layer.  Sending and receiving these packets is done automatically by your bluetooth hardware device.  These packets are never passed up across the host control interface (HCI) to the host software stack, so there is no opportunity for you to sniff them via software.  To sniff this traffic requires an external bluetooth sniffer that captures the over-the-air traffic.

Why do you want to sniff POLL/NULL packets?

Comment: Hi @TJD, thanks for the answer! I'm interested because I was trying to verify if and how the sniff mode for my chip works. :)

Comment: There are some HCI messages that relate to sniff mode that you could monitor.  On linux you can use hcidump to get a trace of all HCI traffic, which can be viewed in wireshark.  When your device enters sniff mode, you will get a Mode Change Event that indicates the mode and the applicable sniff parameters.